# Visual Studio 2012 - No Model Folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I started a project in Visual Studio 2012. I selected the ASP.NET Web Forms Application but the folder structure does not contain a model folder. Is there a setting there needs to be changed for this to be created? However, creating a similar project in Visual Studio 2013 contains a model folder. Is there a difference because of the Visual Studio editions?

Answer (score 1):

It is new in Visual Studio 2013. Previously, it was only MVC with a Models folder as it has Model-View-Controller architecture, an I think Microsoft found out it is a good idea to keep models in a Model folder even when it is Web Form. 
You can create it manually. Click on the project name on solution explorer, right click, on menu go to add-> New Folder and call it Models

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET web forms template does not include a Models folder, you're looking for ASP.NET MVC instead.[image]

Comment: So is there a way to create a model using the DB first approach?